# "invalid syntax error" with lamba usage in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I've below code that works on python3 but gives invalid syntax error on python2.

```
button = QPushButton('Click')
button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, row=row, column=column: self.myfunction(row, column))
```

**Error seen:**

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, row=row, column=column: self.myfunction(row, column))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix this for python2.7?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7 variable arguments must be listed after regular arguments, so a function with a signature like `*args, row=row, column=column` is not allowed.

To port this Python 3 function back to Python 2.7, you would have to use variable keyword arguments:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, **kwargs: self.myfunction(kwargs.get('row', row), kwargs.get('column', column)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though this solves syntax problem, but creates different issue.

Comment: The row value doesn't get updated.
    
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(4)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)

        col = 0
        for row in range(4):
                button = QPushButton('Click')
                self.table.setCellWidget(row,col,button)
                button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, **kwargs: self.myfunction(kwargs.get('row', row), kwargs.get('column', col)))
        
        self.table.show()
        
    def myfunction(self,row,col):
        print("row ",row)